# ORA-22835: Buffer too small for CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW conversion (actual: 4880, maximum: 4000)

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using oracle database. and following is the query:

this is the query used for joining 5 tables and processing based on the value if a field in one of the table.

but I am getting a buffer overflow error

```
select d.*, main.*, s.location 
from(
select ticketid, 
    min(dte_soc_discipline),
     sum(oper)  oper,
    sum(maint) maint,
    sum(ohl) ohl,
    sum(ugl) ugl,
    sum(ct) ct,
    sum(pri) pri,
    sum(relay) relay,
    sum(pwreq)  pwreq,    
    max(memo)  memo
    --case when sum(memo) > 0 then 1 else null end as memo
from (
select s.ticketid, 
    s.description, s.dte_soc_discipline, s.targetstart, s.targetfinish,
    case when regexp_like (REGEXP_SUBSTR(wld.text,'(OPERATOR\w*\s*)(-|:)(.*?)(--|$|:)',regexp_instr(wld.text,'SYSTEM\s*SUPERVISOR',1,1) + 1,1,'i'),'5/3[^0-9]') then 1 else 0 end as Oper,
    case when regexp_like (REGEXP_SUBSTR(wld.text,'(MAINT\w*\s*)(-|:)(.*?)(--|$|:)',regexp_instr(wld.text,'SYSTEM\s*SUPERVISOR',1,1) + 1,1,'i'),'5/3[^0-9]') then 1 else 0 end as Maint,
    case when regexp_like (REGEXP_SUBSTR(wld.text,'(LINE\w*\s*)(-|:)(.*?)(--|$|:)',regexp_instr(wld.text,'SYSTEM\s*SUPERVISOR',1,1) + 1,1,'i'),'OHL([^U]|U[^G]|UG[^L])*?5/3[^0-9]') then 1 else 0 end as OHL,
    case when regexp_like (REGEXP_SUBSTR(wld.text,'(LINE\w*\s*)(-|:)(.*?)(--|$|:)',regexp_instr(wld.text,'SYSTEM\s*SUPERVISOR',1,1) + 1,1,'i'),'UGL([^O]|O[^H]|OH[^L])*?5/3[^0-9]') then 1 else 0 end as UGL,
    case when regexp_like (REGEXP_SUBSTR(wld.text,'(\sCT\s*|\sCABLE\sT\w*\s*)(-|:)(.*?)(--|$|:)',regexp_instr(wld.text,'SYSTEM\s*SUPERVISOR',1,1) + 1,1,'i'),'5/3[^0-9]') then 1 else 0 end as CT,
    case when regexp_like (REGEXP_SUBSTR(wld.text,'(PRIMARY SERVICES\w*\s*|PRIMARY\w*\s*)(-|:)(.*?)(--|$|:)',regexp_instr(wld.text,'SYSTEM\s*SUPERVISOR',1,1) + 1,1,'i'),'5/3[^0-9]') then 1 else 0 end as Pri,
    0 as relay,
    case when regexp_like (REGEXP_SUBSTR(wld.text,'(PERT\s*)(-|:)(.*?)(--|$|:)',regexp_instr(wld.text,'SYSTEM\s*SUPERVISOR',1,1) + 1,1,'i'),'5/3[^0-9]') then 1 else 0 end as PwrEq, --'(PHAS|FINAL|APPR).*?12/2[^0-9]'
    substr(wld.rtext,regexp_instr(wld.text,'SYSTEM\s*SUPERVISOR',1,1,0,'n')) as memo

from sr s
left join worklog wl on wl.recordkey = s.ticketid and wl.class = 'SR' and wl.logtype = 'SOC_RSD'
left join (select REGEXP_REPLACE(translate(upper(ldtext), chr(10) || chr(13) || chr(09), ' '),'<.*?>') as text, 
                  REGEXP_REPLACE(to_char(ldtext),'<.*?>') as rtext, 
                  ldkey, 
                  ldtext 
           from longdescription 
           where ldownertable = 'WORKLOG') wld on wld.ldkey = wl.worklogid
where s.classstructureid = '47177'
    and s.status = 'INPROG'
    and wl.recordkey is not null

union all

select s.ticketid, s.description, s.dte_soc_discipline, s.targetstart, s.targetfinish, 
    case when s.dte_soc_discipline in ('SUBSTA','PERT') and s.location not like '%PP' then 1
        else 0 end as OPER,
    case when s.dte_soc_discipline = 'SUBSTA' and upper(substr(ld.ldtext, 1, 30)) not like '%CONTRACT%' then 1 else 0 end as MAINT,
    case when s.dte_soc_discipline = 'OHL' then 1 else 0 end as OHL,
    case when s.dte_soc_discipline = 'UGL' then 1 else 0 end as UGL,
    0 as ct,
    0 as pri,
    case when s.dte_soc_discipline = 'PERT' then 1 else 0 end as RELAY,
    0 as pwreq,
    '' as memo
from sr s
left join longdescription ld on ld.ldkey = s.ticketuid and ldownertable = 'TICKET' and ldownercol = 'DESCRIPTION' 
where s.classstructureid = '47177'
    and s.status = 'INPROG'

    and (to_char(to_date('5-03-2021','MM-DD-YYYY'),'D') in ('1','7')  -- If weekend, only check if TS or TF equals date
            and (trunc(s.targetstart) = to_date('5-03-2021','MM-DD-YYYY') 
                 or trunc(s.targetfinish) = to_date('5-03-2021','MM-DD-YYYY'))
        or
        (to_char(to_date('5-03-2021','MM-DD-YYYY'),'D') in ('2','3','4','5','6') --If weekday, check if TS <= Date <= TF
            and trunc(s.targetstart) <= to_date('5-03-2021','MM-DD-YYYY') 
            and trunc(s.targetfinish) >= to_date('5-03-2021','MM-DD-YYYY')))
    and s.dte_soc_discipline in ('OHL','PERT','SUBSTA','UGL')) 
where (oper > 0 or maint > 0 or ohl > 0 or ugl > 0 or ct > 0 or pri > 0 or relay > 0 or pwreq > 0) -- Only show RSDs with resources
group by ticketid) main 
left join sr s on s.ticketid = main.ticketid
left join (select dte_key1 as Substation,
    dte_key3 as SC,
    dte_key4 as Region
from dte_domaindata
where dte_listname = 'DTE_SUBSTNREG') d on d.Substation = s.location
```

following is the error output:

```
ORA-22835: Buffer too small for CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW conversion (actual: 4880, maximum: 4000)
22835. 00000 -  "Buffer too small for CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW conversion (actual: %s, maximum: %s)"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to convert CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW, where
           the LOB size was bigger than the buffer limit for CHAR and RAW
           types.
           Note that widths are reported in characters if character length
           semantics are in effect for the column, otherwise widths are
           reported in bytes.
*Action:   Do one of the following
           1. Make the LOB smaller before performing the conversion,
           for example, by using SUBSTR on CLOB
           2. Use DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR to convert CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW.
```

Comment: If you don't know which part of the query is the problem, then you can isolate the two union'd queries as a starting point.

Comment: Please, provide [**minimal** reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @JeffHolt I appreciate your input. Lower Half is working fine (when I commented portion above "union all". I am having trouble in understanding error and how regex methods are related to it.

Comment: @astentx I thought bigger picture will give better idea. Now I am sure its upper portion above "Union all" creating problem.

Comment: Continue whittling down the query until you find the smallest amount of code that reproduces the problem. Then edit your post to include only *that* minimal but complete and reproducible code. Most people using that process solve their own problems.

Comment: @aman No, the only way to find the root cause is to locate it with the narrowest query possible. If you try to minimize the code, you'll have a good chance to find the operator which gives you error. Then with filtering you'll locate the rows which produce the error. It is not fast, but it always works and allows you to resolve the issue by yourself or leads to the very specific question with a concrete answer.

Comment: @astentx When I limit output result to 95 rows its running without error.

Comment: The error is not about rowcount, but about some long text. Most possible reason: you apply some function or comparison that (implicitly) uses varchar, but the input is clob.

Comment: Candidates are: `to_char(ldtext)` and `translate(upper(ldtext)` because they use type conversion (translate does not support clob). So you need to find a very long `ldtext`